# How the depth of the vertices changes along the route in the splay tree after search

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, splay-trees

Studying for the exam in "Advanced Algorithms" course. I'm trying to solve the following question:

> This question discusses a search operation for a vertex `x` in a splay tree. Determine how the depth of the vertices changes along the route from the root of the tree to `x` when, during the splay to the root, zig-zag and zig-zig actions are performed exactly alternately.

As I understand, we asked to perform `zig-zag,zig-zig,zig-zag,zig-zig,...zig-zag,zig-zig`.

I'm not sure what is the answer but I was trying to [run a few examples](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/SplayTree.html). For example, if `x=2` we get:

[image]

And if `x=15` then we get:

[image]

Looking into those two examples, I can't seem to figure the pattern. Also, I'm not sure what is the expected answer - should there be some formula that I need to construct?

Comment: The [splay tree paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3828.3835) states that the 3 splay rotations are meant to halve the path used to access $x$.

Comment: @Russel So what does it gives us?